# How to call a function while running a Java web application?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a web application in Java (Netbeans). And I have a function that should be called exactly while running the web application, without putting it into the static method **main**.

I really don't have any idea about how to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Web applications dont have a main method. Are you trying to run a scheduled job?

Comment: yes, I succeeded to make a scheduled job thanks to quartz. But my problem is that I don't know how to run a function exactly while deploying my application. Thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6016232/680925.

Comment: One of the answers on the link u gave me is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184835/call-method-on-undeploy-from-a-java-web-application but it didn't work for me. So i'm going to try the other solutions and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that implements ServletConextListener :

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ListenToMeFirst implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // Run me First while deploying!!!

    }

}
```

Don't forget to put it in your web.xml file :

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>path.to.yourListenerClass.ListenToMeFirst</listener-class>
</listener>
```