# Executing task after deployment of Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer

I have a Java EE application which should start a synchronization process with an external system once after its deployment.

How could I implement this requirement?

Comment: Do you really want the process to start at "deployment" (i.e., a new EAR) or at startup (JEE server re-start)?

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992602/how-to-call-a-function-while-running-a-java-web-application/17445847#17445847), it might be what you mean.

Comment: I simply would like to ensure that the synchronisation process will be started after the deployment or at server start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested the suggested solution which uses the `@Startup` and `@PostConstruct` annotations. It turned out that Glassfish does not complete the deployment of an application until all methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` have finished. So in my case the deployment would take from several minutes up to an hour.

But I figured out a different way to achive what I want. The best solution seems to be a timer callback method which cancels its timer after its execution.

```java
@Stateless
public class SynchronisationService {
    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", persistent = false)
    protected void init(Timer timer)
    {
       doTheSync();

       timer.cancel();
    }
 }
```

Using a non-persistent timer allows the timer to be re-created if the application server is restarted.

Comment: why did you use a stateless bean and not a singleton, I am using singleton, and it works but i get time retries every minute, while the job is running ... which throw an error.

Answer (score 28):

Below are listed a couple of popular methods for getting lifecycle callbacks in JavaEE apps.

**Create a javax.servlet.ServletContextListener implementation**

If you have a web component to your .ear file (embedded .war) or your deployment is a .war by itself you can add a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your `web.xml` and get a callback when the server starts or is shutting down.

Example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question

import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        /* Do Startup stuff. */
   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        /* Do Shutdown stuff. */
   }

}
```

and then add this configuration to your `web.xml` deployment descriptor.
`$WAR_ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.stackoverflow.question.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**Create an EJB 3.1 @Startup Bean**

This method uses an EJB 3.1 singleton to get a startup and shutdown callback from the server.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class LifecycleBean {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    /* Startup stuff here. */
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
    /* Shutdown stuff here */
  }

}
```

Comment: That package is wrong. Why no `@WebListener`? Are you googling answers for OP or so?

Comment: @BalusC I didn't know about `@WebListener` I've always configured `ServletContextListeners` using `web.xml`. I'm not exactly sure how it works so I don't want to give wrong advice. Also which package did I get wrong?

Comment: @BalusC Found it. I don't know how I missed that wrong package name. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `<listener>` needs `</listener>` closing tag

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `@Startup` and `@PostConstruct` annotations to perform tasks on application startup.

Comment: From my experience the `@PostConstruct` annotation should be only used for initialisation tasks which need only a few minutes. The synchronisation with an external system needs much longer. Therefore the synchronisation should not be bound to the initialisation of the bean itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), or a servlet that is initialized at startup, for example. Of course, this becomes much harder if you have multiple deployments of the application in a cluster, and only want this process to be run once.