# Initialising Database Master Tables at App Server Startup Jboss AS 7

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets, jboss, ejb

i'm using Jboss AS 7 and a Webapp that conncts to database from App Server DataSource. there are tables in Database which i might require to frequently query like Master Tables (e.g Country Master) and populate in dropdown. 'What would be the best method to Query and keep the results in Beans or Data Objects and retrive it from memory whenever required.
any frameworks available or App Server's capability can be usilized ?
pls suggest.

Comment: Please read the SO rules. These type of questions are not valid.

Comment: how different is my Q's from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513455/how-to-run-a-time-consuming-task-on-startup-in-a-web-application-while-deploying ? but didnt get much clarity from that. sure will refer to SO rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate tool can help you solve this issues. There is a secondary cache level which can help you store the values in the cache through out the application lifetime. (of-course you can delete update the cache when you think it needs to be updated)

Link to the topic [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm). Managing the secondary cache [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-sessioncache), and
[example code](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-second-level-cache-example/)